# ActiveRecord: Exclude group if at least one record within it doesn't meet condition

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have two models: an `owner` and a `pet`.  An owner `has_many :pets` and a pet `belongs_to :owner`.

What I want to do is grab *only those owners* that have *pets which ALL weigh over 30lbs*.

```rb
#app/models/owner.rb
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pets
  #return only those owners that have heavy pets
end

#app/models/pet.rb
class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner
  scope :heavy, ->{ where(["weight > ?", 30])}
end
```

Here is what is in my database. I have three owners:

1. *Neil*, and *ALL of which ARE heavy*;
2. *John*, and *ALL of which ARE NOT heavy*;
3. *Bob*, and *SOME of his pets ARE heavy* and *SOME that ARE NOT heavy*.

The query should return only *Neil*.  Right now my attempts return *Neil* and *Bob*.

Comment: I have found the most useful resource for determining things like *Why am I getting that result* in rails query is simple. Try calling `Owner.heavy_pets.to_sql` and that should give you a great idea about why. As suggested below adding `uniq` or `distinct` should limit the result set to what you intend.

Comment: The query you are interested in is not clear from the description. Do you want something like this? ``Owner.only_if_they_have_heavy_pets`` ?

Comment: @MariusPop yes.  Only grab any Owner that has ALL heavy pets.  So if an owner has 50 pets and only one of those pets is not heavy, then don't grab that owner.  If an owner has 50 pets and all 50 of his pets are heavy, then grab that owner.

Comment: And, by the way: ___I want to  grab only those owners that have pets which ALL weigh over 30lbs___ - you want only heavy dogs. ___Neil, and ALL of which ARE NOT heavy___. And then you write, that you want to return Neil. Is this a typo and you want John instead?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?And also, which Rails version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you do it in two steps, first you get all `owner_ids` that have at least 1 heavy pet, then get all `owner_ids` that have at least 1 not-heavy pet and then grab the owners where id exists in the first array but not in the second?

Something like:

```
scope :not_heavy, -> { where('weight <= ?', 30) }
```

...

```
owner_ids = Pet.heavy.pluck(:owner_id) - Pet.not_heavy.pluck(:owner_id)
owners_with_all_pets_heavy = Owner.where(id: owner_ids)
```

Comment: I wouldn't want to do this for very large data sets though.

Answer (score 4):

You can form a group for each `owner_id` and check, if all rows within group match required condition *or at least one row doesn't match it*, you can achieve it with `group by` and `having` clauses:

```
scope :heavy, -> { group("owner_id").having(["count(case when weight <= ? then weight end) = 0", 30]) }
```

There is also another option, more of a Rails-ActiverRecord approach:

```
scope :heavy, -> { where.not(owner_id: Pet.where(["weight <= ?", 30]).distinct.pluck(:owner_id)).distinct }
```

Here you get all `owner_id`s that don't fit condition (*searching by contradiction*) and exclude them from the result of original query.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't this simply a matter of finding the owners for whom the minimum pet weight is greater than some value:

```
scope :heavy, -> { group("owner_id").joins(:pets).having("min(pets.weight) >= ?", 30)}
```

Or conversely,

```
scope :light, -> { group("owner_id").joins(:pets).having("max(pets.weight) < ?", 30)}
```

These are scopes on the Owner, by the way, not the Pet

Another approach is to turn this into a scope on Owner:

```
Owner.where(Pet.where.not("pets.owner_id = owners.id and pets.weight < ?", 30).exists)
```

Subtly different, as it is checking for the non-existence of a per with a weight less than 30, so if an owner has no pets then this condition will match for that owner.

In database terms, this is going to be the most efficient query for large data sets.

Indexing of pets(owner_id, weight) is recommended for both these approaches.

Comment: Your solution is great! Only concern is that it duplicates the `heavy` scope located in the `Pet` model. Is there a way to use your approach, but utilize the`heavy` scope located in the`Pet` model for those `min` and `max` aggregates? I  know that `merge` is used in this scenario but with this query I'm not sure how to apply it.

Comment: I can't think of a way of doing that, but in any case I see these as being fundamentally different scopes. I think that that you really ought to have, if you were aiming for the optimum query efficiency (which you should be), is a NOT EXISTS correlated subquery, for which you'd have to dip into Arel.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a the `uniq` to your scope:

```
scope :heavy_pets, -> { uniq.joins(:pets).merge(Pet.heavy) }
```

It works on a database level, using the `distinct` query.

Comment: I realized that this does not in fact work.  What this query does is it grabs all owners that have at least one heavy pet.  That is not what I'm trying to do here though.  I want to grab only those owners where ALL of their associated pets are heavy.